# EditText SetPosition

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make when I click on my EditText cursor position go to the end of the text, my code is as follows:

```
tb_acrescimo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int position = tb_acrescimo.length();
            Editable etext = tb_acrescimo.getText();
            Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
        }
    });
```

But it works on Android API 2.3 but does not work on 4.1, does anyone know what should I do?

I find other solution for my problem but don't answer my question, flees the topic, so I will not post the solution, ok?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? It doesn't do the selection?

Comment: My intention is put the cursor in the end of the EditText when clicking on it, but this not working

Comment: And on 4.1 the `Selection.setSelection(etext, position)` does nothing?

Comment: Neither one works, I think the function is not correct, OnFocusChanged is the same right?

Comment: Is `tb_acrescimo` the EditText? If so, use `tb_acrescimo.setSelection(position);`

Comment: I had already tried that way, but not works

Comment: If the EditText already has the focus when you click on it, `onFocusChange()` isn't going to fire.

Comment: In this case the correct use would be OnTouchListener?

Comment: Maybe. Keep in mind, though, that that will pretty much prevent the user from positioning the cursor anywhere else in the EditText with touch events, unless you do a check for `hasFocus()`

Comment: This will be no problem, if I understand what you mean, i only need to click in the Edit and the cursor move to the end, then the User can change it position

Comment: ie whenever the User to change the focus to the edit cursor should move to the end position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tb_acrescimo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) return;
        int position = tb_acrescimo.length();
        Editable etext = tb_acrescimo.getText();
        tb_acrescimo.setSelection(etext, position);
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is that the android 4.1 it places the cursor at the last position but then back to the first, and nowhere do my source do it

Comment: try `tb_acrescimo.setSelection(position);` instead of `tb_acrescimo.setSelection(etext, position);`

Comment: sorry by my delay, but i tested your solution and not works. This is so weird, they works in phones 2.3 but in 4.1 don't

Comment: I find other solution for my problem but don't answer my question, flees the topic, so I will not post the solution, ok?

Comment: it's up to you if you want to share it or not